# How to apply same function on previous calculated result in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a Haskell function that ***returns*** a list `(h:t)`.
I want to apply the function recursively on its own results. Like this:

```
func (inp1) -> result1;
func (result1) -> result2;
func (result2) -> result3;
...
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

There is [`iterate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:iterate) which seems to fit the bill:

```
result = take however_many_you_need $ iterate func initial_value
```

Haskell's laziness guarantees that `func` will be calculated just enough times.

Comment: Iterate can be applied to specific functions? I mean, can I apply iterate to a function like func::[String]->String->[[String]]?

Comment: It expectedly only works for functions that return the same type that they accept. Else you cannot apply that function to its own result. So `[String] -> [String]` would be acceptable, and `[String] -> [[String]]` would not be. Same is true for your code fragment in the question.

Comment: If you have `f :: [String] -> [[String]]` you can still iterate with `iterate (concat . f)`, which will simply collect all of the result lists into one list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want something like this

```
funcApplier inp
    | isDone inp = inp
    | otherwise = funcApplier (func inp)
```

where `isDone` is a boolean-returning function that determines that your input is in the state that you desire.

Comment: Or you could use "takeUntil isDone $ iterate func initialValue"